# Is it possible to find the number of triangles that can be formed from a list of lengths in better than (n choose 3) time?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, time-complexity, complexity-theory

This relates to a larger problem I'm working on.

For example, let's say we're given a list

```
9 5 6 1
```

The *possible* triangles would have sides of length

```
(9,5,6)
(9,6,1)
(9,5,1)
(5,6,1)
```

and the ones that are valid (by the triangle inequality) are

```
(9,5,6)
(5,6,1)
```

Is it possible to find those valid ones in better-than-`O(n choose 3)` time?

Comment: @Deadly Nicotine, what so you mean by O(n choose 3), is it O(n^3) ?

Comment: @Abdenaceur Lichiheb He's talking about a Binomial coefficient

Comment: @AbdenaceurLichiheb Yes, sorry. I meant to say that there are N choose 3 such possibilities, but the brute force algorithm for finding those possibilities is indeed O(N^3)

Comment: Whether this question is on-topic here is being [discussed on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/335730/1709587).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In general case, the answer is *no*: imagine that you're given

```
 1, 1 - ε, 1 - 2 * ε, ..., 1 - (n - 1) * ε
```

In that very case all combinations of 3 items

```
 n * (n - 1) * (n - 2) / 6 = O(n**3)
```

are *distinct* and make *valid triangles* and you have `O(n**3)` complexity just to *enumerate* (and *output*) them

Answer (score 3):

First sort your list.

Now instead of doing complete O(n^3) search, we only need to search for pair of points in O(n^2) and find the third point ( maybe more than one point, so you need to check for lower bound and upper bound ) by doing a binary search.

So overall the new complexity is O(n^2 log(n))

Comment: yes, but this is just counting them, in case you want the actual triples generated, worst case scenario is still `O(n^3)`, because you need to somehow generate the output

Comment: @cobarzan, yeah you are right, sure i'm just given the number of triangles, but if you need  the actual triples, then it's defiantly O(n^3) , but still considered as a local optimization.

Answer (score 2):

No. You could have an arbitrarily large set of inputs where every triple is a valid triangle.